# Java: Deleting Elements in an ArrayList using Their Value

Tags: java, arraylist

I was asked to demonstrate a *Singleton class* design for my assignment. The version I submitted uses **Strings** and works fine, but I just can't get the **reserveLane** method to work properly with integers. Whenever I call the **reserveLane** method in the code below, *it removes the element with the index of the integer passed into it instead of the element containing the value that matches the integer passed in*. The program is supposed to print each message in the **removeLane** method once.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Race {
    // store one instance
    private static final Race INSTANCE = new Race(); // (this is the singleton)
    List<Integer> lanes = new ArrayList<>();
    public static Race getInstance() { // callers can get to
        return INSTANCE; // the instance
    }

    private Race() {
        lanes.add(1);
        lanes.add(2);
    }

    public void removeLane(int lane) {
        if(lanes.contains(lane)){
            lanes.remove(lane);
            System.out.println("Lane successfully reserved.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Lane is already reserved.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        assignLane(1);
        assignLane(1);
    }

    private static void assignLane(int lane) {
        Race race = Race.getInstance();
        race.removeLane(lane);
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if I'm wasting my time trying to go this route or is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Try using `lanes.remove(new Integer(lane));` instead

Answer (score 3):

```
Integer integer = new Integer(lane);
lanes.remove(integer);
```

Your `lanes` is an arraylist of `Integer` objects, not `int`. Passing an `int` to `Arraylist.remove(int index)` will remove an object at that index, but if you pass an `Integer` object, the `remove()` function will delete the first occurrence of that object.

Comment: You can see the documentation for the methods described above [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are using primitive type to do your removal of element. You can convert it the Wrapper class and do it. Change the `removeLane` method as follows:

```
public void removeLane(Integer lane) {
    if(lanes.contains(lane)){
       lanes.remove(lane);
       System.out.println("Lane successfully reserved.");
}
    else{
        System.out.println("Lane is already reserved.");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList Docs

> `E remove(int index)`- Removes the element at the specified position in this list.
>
> `boolean  remove(Object o)` - Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present.

As you have sent an `int` primitive type to method `remove` it has called `remove(int index)`. Instead just send an `Integer` object and then it will call method `remove(Object o)` and it will work fine.

Working Code:

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Race {

    private static final Race INSTANCE // store one instance
            = new Race(); // (this is the singleton)
    List<Integer> lanes = new ArrayList<>();

    public static Race getInstance() { // callers can get to
        return INSTANCE; // the instance
    }

    private Race() {
        lanes.add(1);
        lanes.add(2);
    }

    public void removeLane(int lane) {
        if (lanes.contains(lane)) {
            lanes.remove((Integer) lane);
            System.out.println("Lane successfully reserved.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Lane is already reserved.");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        assignLane(1);
        assignLane(1);
    }

    private static void assignLane(int lane) {
        Race race = Race.getInstance();
        race.removeLane(lane);
    }
}
```